# 変数にhtml　(pタグ、hタグなど入れたい）

Tags: php, laravel

コントローラーの中のメソッドの中の変数に、htmlの構文を入れ込む方法で迷っております。

```
public function show(profile $profile){
$text = "プロフィール\n" .
        "{$profile->name}\n" .
        "仕事\n" .
        "{$profile->job}\n" .
        "スキル\n" .
        "{$profile->skill}\n" .
        "自己紹介\n" .
        "{$profile->introduction}";
return view ('profile' => $profile,);
}
```

`$text` の変数の中に、以下のようなhtmlの構文を代入したいのですが、うまくいきません。
(h5,pなどにstyleをあてたい）

```html
<h5>プロフィール</h5>
<p>{$profile->name}</p>
<h6>仕事</h6>
<p>{$profile->job}</p>
<h6>スキル</h6>
<p>{$profile->skill}</p>
<h6>自己紹介</h6>
<p>{$profile->introduction}</p>
```

**＜試したこと＞**

```
$a = "プロフィール";
$text = '<h5>' . $a . '</h5>';
```

`<h5>` などもテキストとして吐き出されてしまう。

どなたか、ご教示いただけましたら幸いです。

Comment: 全く別の視点ですが、HTMLタグのサニタイズを外すとXSSの脆弱性が発生する可能性がありますので、`$profile->name`に不正なHTMLが入らないようにアプリ側で制御する必要があります。そのためコントローラーで制御するのでなくてできるだけView側で制御したほうが良いかと思います。

Answer (score 0):

と書いたら出来ると思います

```
$text = <<< EOM　　
    "プロフィール\n" .
    "{$profile->name}\n" .
    "仕事\n" .
    "{$profile->job}\n" .
    "スキル\n" .
    "{$profile->skill}\n" .
    "自己紹介\n" .
    "{$profile->introduction}";
EOM;
```